# npm installs different version than specified in package.json, how is this possible ? how to fix this?

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules

If I use the `package.json` given below to execute `npm install` then that will install `react-15.4.2` (see `npm ls` below) even though I specified version `15.3.2`.

How is this possible ?

Why is this happening?

How can I avoid this ?

content of `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sbt-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Webpack configuration for sbt-demo",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "dist": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "ghooks": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp-decompress": "^1.1.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "imagemin": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.14.1",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.9.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "highlight.js": "8.9.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.2",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-update": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-geomicons": "^2.0.4",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.13.9",
    "react-infinite": "^0.7.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-beta",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.2.0",
    "react-spinner": "^0.2.3",
    "react-tagsinput": "^3.0.3",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "svg-loader": "0.0.2"
  }
}
```

`npm ls` gives:

```
├─┬ react@15.4.2
│ ├─┬ fbjs@0.8.9
│ │ ├── core-js@1.2.7
│ │ ├─┬ isomorphic-fetch@2.2.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ node-fetch@1.6.3
│ │ │ │ └─┬ encoding@0.1.12
│ │ │ │   └── iconv-lite@0.4.15
│ │ │ └── whatwg-fetch@2.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ promise@7.1.1
│ │ │ └── asap@2.0.5
│ │ ├── setimmediate@1.0.5
│ │ └── ua-parser-js@0.7.12
│ └─┬ loose-envify@1.3.1
│   └── js-tokens@3.0.1
├── react-addons-create-fragment@15.3.2
├── react-addons-css-transition-group@15.3.2
├── react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.3.2
├── react-addons-transition-group@15.3.2
├── react-addons-update@15.3.2
├── react-dom@15.4.2
├─┬ react-geomicons@2.1.0
│ └── geomicons-open@3.0.0-beta.2
├─┬ react-grid-layout@0.13.9
│ ├── lodash.isequal@4.5.0
│ ├── react-draggable@2.2.3
│ └── react-resizable@1.6.0
├─┬ react-hot-loader@1.3.1
│ ├── react-hot-api@0.4.7
│ └─┬ source-map@0.4.4
│   └── amdefine@1.0.1
├─┬ react-infinite@0.7.3
│ ├── lodash.isarray@3.0.4
│ ├── lodash.isfinite@3.2.0
│ ├── object-assign@4.0.1
│ ├─┬ react@0.14.8
│ │ ├─┬ envify@3.4.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ jstransform@11.0.3
│ │ │ │ ├── base62@1.1.2
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ commoner@0.10.8
│ │ │ │ │ ├── detective@4.3.2
│ │ │ │ │ ├── private@0.1.7
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ recast@0.11.22
│ │ │ │ │   ├── ast-types@0.9.5
│ │ │ │ │   ├── esprima@3.1.3
│ │ │ │ │   └── source-map@0.5.6
│ │ │ │ ├── esprima-fb@15001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb
│ │ │ │ └── object-assign@2.1.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you gave "react" a caret sign `"react": "^15.3.2"` it will always fetch the latest version which is less than 16.0.0.

To get the exact version of react remove the caret before the version `"react": "15.3.2"`.

But by doing so you have to manually check/change the version dependencies for other dependencies which use react. Since they might be incompatible with the version of react you specify.

For official docs refer https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004.

Comment: Many thanks ! How do I see these incompatibilities ? Is there some warning/tool for it ?

Comment: npm will usually throw warnings if peer dependency requirements are not met. Just try a npm install with "react": "15.3.2". You will see warnings.